# How are factor level coefficient estimates combined for total Wald chi-squared?

Tags: anova, glmm, wald-test

I have been working with mixed-effects models, with both continuous and categorical variables. I am interested in the combined effect of categorical variables with > 2 levels. I ran type II ANOVA on my models and intuitively understand the Wald chi-squared values produced by this test. What I am unclear about is *how* these chi-squared values are computed when there are more than two levels to a categorical variable.

For a continuous predictor or a categorical predictor with only two levels, Wald chi-squared is equal to the coefficient estimate divided by variance in that estimate (β^2/var[β]). For such predictors, the chi-squared I computed by hand matches up with what I see in the table.

For categorical predictors with more than two levels, the collective chi-squared value is not equal to the sum of individual coefficients divided by their individual variances. Under the null hypothesis that all effects are equal to zero, for a three-level categorical variable I think it should be:

(β1+β2)^2/(var(β1)+var(β2)-2*cov(β1,β2))

...but that doesn't add up to the numbers I'm seeing in my ANOVA table. I suspect I'm either combining the estimates in the wrong way -or- missing a step that would account for unequal sample sizes in the groups. I computed weighted mean and variance, but that still did not produce the numbers I see in the table.

What is the procedure for combining coefficient estimates to produce a single chi-squared value, and does this take into account unequal sample sizes?